# How do I make my pen-drive writable?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I cannot create a new folder in my 8GIGA pen drive. There is no clickable option to do this after I right click on the files. I cannot paste anything in the pen drive as well.

I tried going to the pen drive properties and change *Group and Others* access to create and delete, but this shows up.

[image]

Comment: There may be a hardware read-only switch.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky solve the problem.